# How to execute Apex code on Milestone Violation

Tags: casemilestone

Does anybody have an idea on how to execute Apex code on a Milestone Violation Action?

Currently, I am willing to post a Case Feed Item when a given Milestone Violoation happens.

I have already achieved this setting a field on the Case and firing a trigger on that change, but I dont want to define more Case custom fields only for the other Milestones I have.

Any idea would be welcome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a formula field and a trigger is definitely the easiest and safest option. Remember that you can hide the field from the layout if that's your concern.

I you don't want to add another field, you would have to fallback to a scheduled Apex job that gets 'expired' cases. This requires a lot more code and it's far less precise. Not recommended.